# Reading jt400 xpcml from a stream instead of a file to create a ProgramCallDocument

Tags: java, jaxb, ibm-midrange, jt400

I have about 1500 RPG/CL programs I want to call from my Web App.  So... I have about 1500 xpcml files.

I can (and already do statically) build xpcml using JAX_B as the jt400 toolkit provides an xsd schema and my Java functions know the parameters of the RPG/CL programs so I'd like to not need the files to exist, and just build a JAX_B bean on the fly and marshall it into the jt400 ProgramCallDocument.

I don't see a ProgramCallDocument constructor that could support that.  Am I blind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this, but take a look at this constructor ...

[ProgramCallDocument(AS400 sys, String docName, ClassLoader loader, InputStream xsdStream)](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/data/ProgramCallDocument.html#ProgramCallDocument(com.ibm.as400.access.AS400,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.io.InputStream))